# Killing Clickonce application using javascript

Tags: javascript

i have a webpage that runs clickonce application on button click,my question is
Is it possible to stop clickonce application(publish on web/available online only!) using javascript?

Comment: Can you provide an example, where the ClickOnce is not disabled yet?

Comment: i published my clickonce app using vs2010 on localhost, when you look at the code of the .htm file, there is a javascript code that runs the .manifest,.application extension. is there a way of closing that application using javascript?

Comment: Without code it's hard to be helpful (I'm not interested in looking up everything you mean, your specific code would be way more helpful). It would be most helpful if your entire site would be publicly accessible :)